# how to remove the error shown by the json file when I change it to frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests

import requests

url = "https://corona-virus-world-and-india-data.p.rapidapi.com/api"

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "04b9735d81mshf7bd2b7070903eap1ec6f9jsnbf3d52c11b5d",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "corona-virus-world-and-india-data.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
print(response)

parsed_data = json.loads(response)
print(parsed_data)

def flatten_json(json):
   dict1 = {}
   def flatten(i, name= dict1):
      if type(i) is dict:
         for a in i:
             flatten(i[a], name + a + ‘_’)
      else:
         dict1[name[:-1]] = i
   flatten(json)
   return dict1
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(flatten_json(parsed_data), orient=’index’)

flatten_json(parsed_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# print(response)
{
  "countries_stat":[
    {
      "country_name":"USA",
      "cases":"29,920,366",
      "deaths":"543,571",
      ...
      "deaths_per_1m_population":"1,636",
      "total_tests":"374,406,501",
      "tests_per_1m_population":"1,126,554"
    }
  ],
  "statistic_taken_at":"2021-03-12 00:00:02",
  "world_total":{
    "total_cases":"119,091,428",
    "new_cases":"467,990",
    ...
    "deaths_per_1m_population":"338.8",
    "statistic_taken_at":"2021-03-12 00:00:02"
  }
}
```

```py
# print(type(response))
<class 'dict'>
```

Analyzing the result, the `response` is already `dict` type, to transform the `countries_stat` to dataframe. You can simply do

```py
# The following methods all produce the same output.
df1 = pd.DataFrame(response['countries_stat'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response['countries_stat'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(response['countries_stat'])
```

```
# print(df1)
        country_name       cases   deaths region  ... total_cases_per_1m_population deaths_per_1m_population  total_tests tests_per_1m_population
0                 USA  29,920,366  543,571         ...                        90,028                    1,636  374,406,501               1,126,554
1               India  11,305,877  158,325         ...                         8,137                      114  224,258,293                 161,409
```